# How do I format the data for insert_batch in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have some problems with `insert_batch`. I have inputs like:

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" />
```

In my controller i have:

```
for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    $data[] = array(
        'field' => $this->input->post('text'),
        'filed2' => $this->input->post('user')
    );
}
$this->db->insert_batch('table', $data)
```

What am I doing wrong, and what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Try doing a `echo $this->db->last_query()` right after your insert_batch statement to verify what was inserted.

Comment: Yes, please post the error message.

Comment: What's the problem here?  What's not working?

Answer (score 2):

If your field name has brackets like `name="text[]"`, it will post an array (as you probably know). Considering that, `$this->input->post('text')` will always return the array itself. Currently you're assigning the exact same entire array each time. Try accessing the values by key with the `$i` variable:

```
$text = $this->input->post('text');
$user = $this->input->post('user');

for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++)
{
    $data[] = array(
        'field' => $text[$i],
        'filed2' => $user[$i]
    );
}
$this->db->insert_batch('table', $data)
```

As an alternative that might be more sensible, loop through the `$_POST` data instead, choosing one field name:

```
$text = $this->input->post('text');
$user = $this->input->post('user');
foreach ($text as $key => $value)
{
    $data[] = array(
        'field' => $text[$key],
        'filed2' => $user[$key]
    );
}
```

This way you don't *have* to know how many values to expect, but it's really up to you.

Comment: hi thank you for your code it works half becouse it's sending something like...values(1,3,4t), (null null null) do you know why?

Comment: Without seeing your actual HTML form and inputs, I can only speculate. Basically, the post data you expect is not really there. Why don't you turn error reporting on and read the errors, or use the error logs, or `var_dump()` or any other of the multitude of debugging tools?

Comment: ok i've got many fields like text[] title[] name[] etc and i count how many they are duplicated and i need to inster foreach into database imagine a form with duplicated fields ....

Comment: I've asked you for your *actual* form code, what the error message is, and suggested you use basic debugging. I don't see further help from me being useful at this point as it can only be guessing. If you still have problems and can offer more info, [edit] your post with the specific details and actual code.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of users searching for '$this->db->insert_batch formatting' the following may be of interest.
I was searching for a way to pack a lot of information into an array and insert it into a database table as one operation. I thought insert_batch might do but it has a caveat I didn't expect:
When formatting the array, the field-names must be identical in each sub-array I.E the following will NOT work:

```
 $data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'first-name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'last-name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);
```